# MACRO symbol usage in IAR Embbeded workbench for MSP430

Tags: msp430, iar

I'm trying to export the symbol of a macro outside a module but the compiler exit with: "Error[34]: May not be redefined"

I'm splitting a program written in IAR assembler in several modules as it was written as a unique big chunk of code. I come across several MACROs supposed to be used as a fast inline function and I'm trying to put them in their related modules and import them as symbols where they are needed. The problem arise when I only add the name/symbol of the macro to the public ones of the module hosting them: even without importing it, the compiler exits with "Error[34]: May not be redefined". If possible I would prefer to keep them whitin the related module. Can I achieve this? Or I'm getting it the wrong way?

```
MODULE      MY_MODULE

PUBLIC      GET_VALUE_XYZ

#include "msp430.h"
#include "defines.s43"

RSEG        CODE

GET_VALUE_XYZ   MACRO   parameter_1
        <...cut...>
        ENDM

    END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros are not functions in a normal sense, they provide short-hand notations for common instruction sequences (somewhat like `#define` macros in C). Thus, macros can only be referred to in modules where the definition is visible. It is not possble to export them to other modules using the `PUBLIC` keyword.

It is possible to separate the macro definitions from the rest of the code and put them in separate files but then you need to include these files using the `#include` directive.